# How to import modules from another folders at different locations [Python]?

Tags: python-2.7, operating-system, sys, sys.path

I have a folder structure like this.

```
Main_Folder
          A
            A1
            A2
              __init__.py
              file1.py
          B
            B1
               B2
                 __init__.py
                 file2.py
```

I would like to import file2 in file1.py , I tried `from B.B1.B2.file2 import *` but did not work. How can i import file2 in file1.py ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `__init__.py` on each directory. like `B` , `B1,` `B2` if you defined `__init__.py`  then only python will understand its package folder...

```
Main_Folder
          A
            __init__.py
            A1
            A2
              __init__.py
              file1.py
          B
            __init__.py
            B1
               __init__.py 
               B2
                 __init__.py
                 file2.py
```

now try `from B.B1.B2.file2 import *` it will work..

Comment: Importing totally works fine in file1.py  (Importing file2.py in file1.py). Let's say another file file3.py (in /B/B3). when i execute file3.py it says, no module found by name file2. what could be the reason ?

Comment: do the same.. put init.py in all sub folders. then only it will identified there is the python file